# Broadcom's NetXtreme II 5709 on Ubuntu 16.10 4.10 kernel fails w/ code model kernel does not support PIC mode

Tags: gcc, broadcom

Is there a way to work with the patch [suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319761/cannot-compile-kernel-error-kernel-does-not-support-pic-mode/319830) to get this to work? I downloaded the [latest drivers from QLogic](http://driverdownloads.qlogic.com/QLogicDriverDownloads_UI/SearchByProduct.aspx?ProductCategory=336&Product=1245&Os=175) (who bought Broadcomm). Their support reply was:

> As of April 13, 2015 we must refer all requests for downloads back to
>   the vendor who supplied the product. All of these products were
>   supplied by another vendor, i.e. Dell, HP, IBM, etc.
>
> We are sorry, but the links we previously provided as NetXtreme II are
>   no longer hosted on the QLogic website.

Here's the error from running make:

```
make -C bnx2/src  KVER=4.8.0-46-generic PREFIX=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/Desktop/linux-7.10.14/linux-7.10.14/Server/Linux/Driver/netxtreme2-7.10.14/bnx2-2.710.10/src'
gcc -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build/include  -DHAVE_GFP -DOLD_NETIF -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -pipe -finline-limit=2000 -O2   -c -o bnx2.o bnx2.c
bnx2.c:1:0: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
 /* bnx2.c: Broadcom NX2 network driver.

<builtin>: recipe for target 'bnx2.o' failed
make[1]: *** [bnx2.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/Desktop/linux-7.10.14/linux-7.10.14/Server/Linux/Driver/netxtreme2-7.10.14/bnx2-2.710.10/src'
Makefile:60: recipe for target 'l2build' failed
make: *** [l2build] Error 2
```

I've tried using GCC 4.7 and 4.8 as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851721/ubuntu-16-10-intel-e1000e-driver-cannot-be-compiled-error-struct-net-device) but keep running into pathing errors, i.e., **No such file or directory** such as this:

```
/lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build/include/linux/sched.h: At top level:
/lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build/include/linux/sched.h:63:35: fatal error: asm-generic/processor.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm-generic/processor.h>
```

Comment: "we must refer all requests for downloads back to the vendor who supplied the product"  <--- well, did you do that?

Comment: It's an older IBM Lenovo ThinkServer TD200 so the drivers haven't been upgraded since 2010: http://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/servers/thinkserver/td200/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Our server had a directory of /lib/firmware/bnx2x (note the extra "x"). I fixed it by running `mkdir /lib/firmware/bnx2` and then from a clue on [this SX thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355157/180291), I downloaded the [bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/linux/distributions/0linux/archives_sources/linux-firmware/linux-firmware/bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw) file into that directory and ran `update-initramfs -u` and rebooted and voila. I shared this solution on [this SX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350350/ubuntu-16-10-not-recognising-bnx2-network-interfaces) thread as well...